# Passenger Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have one landing page and rails app with Passenger+Nginx.
I am trying to do something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;

    if ( $remote_addr ~* ip-address-here ) {

      root /home/app/public;

     # Turn on Passenger
     passenger_enabled on;
     passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/wrappers/ruby;
    }

    #else proxy_pass http://landing_page_ip;
}
```

Comment: There's no else parameter in NGINX. If you're set on using this configuration, put your `proxy_pass` directive in a negated `if` block

Comment: That sounds more reasonable. Good luck!